# How can I echo something that is an in array (such as <a href=arraydata>)

Tags: php

I'm trying to make it where I can go to a link of off a YouTube API. (MP4), but I can't figure out how to make the link to the MP4 clickable (such as `<a href=data>`). I am wanting to do this for a Android project, basically just a completely online Android converter since FLVTO and onlinevideoconverter is super annoying, pops up viruses, or pops up "Your Galaxy S7 Edge is infected! install app to fix!". Here's what I've tried.

```
$formats = $array["streamingData"]["formats"];
    for ($a = 0; $a <= (count($formats) - 1); $a++){
        $data[] = array(
            "url" => $array["streamingData"]["formats"][$a]["url"]
            echo "<a href='"$array['streamingData']['formats'][$a]['url']"'>downloadlink</a>"
```

);

or

```
$formats = $array["streamingData"]["formats"];
    for ($a = 0; $a <= (count($formats) - 1); $a++){
        $data[] = array(
            $url => $array["streamingData"]["formats"][$a]["url"]
        );
        echo "<a href='"$url"'>adsf</a>";
```

Comment: You have a typo when rendering you link, it should probably be "streamingData", not " streaingData"

Comment: Can you clarify the problems with the given code? To me, it looks like you should see any syntax errors pretty clearly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why still put in the array if you want to display? Just do it.

```
 $formats = $array["streamingData"]["formats"];
for ($a = 0; $a <= (count($formats) - 1); $a++){
   echo "<a href='".$formats[$a]['url']."'>downloadlink</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: This answer worked also! All of the answers work, but your answer was first.

Answer (score 3):

You need to concat the string

```
 echo "<a href='" . $url . "'>adsf</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

As eric MC said, either you concatenate the string like so:

```
echo "<a href='" . $url . "'>adsf</a>";
```

Or using printf (which imo is cleaner to read)

```
printf("<a href='%s'>adsf</a>", $url);
```

Comment: This worked too, but the first one to post a working answer was paki leonel.